# Laravel: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 because $request-all() strips empty strings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-error-1048

I have a model with a number of fillable fields

```
class Customer extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [...,'my_field'...]
}
```

I also have a controller to update this table with the following method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Customer $customer)
{
    error_log($request->all());
    $customer->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($customer, 200);
}
```

If I send a request with a body containing an empty string:

```
{
    ...
    "my_field": "",
    ...
}
```

this field will be stripped out by the $request->all() method resulting in an array like this:

```
Array
(
...
[my_field] =>
...
)
```

which then creates this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'my_field' cannot be null

But it should not be null, I want it to be an empty string. What is the standart way to deal with this?

Comment: Why not validate the request before handling it?

Comment: But the request is valid, it contains an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses middleware to convert empty strings on a request to `null`. If you want to prevent this from happening, you should remove the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class` middleware entry from the `$middleware` array in `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

It is transformed in the following function in the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` Middleware:

```
/**
 * Transform the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function transform($key, $value)
{
    return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
}
```

**Note:** you can also manually check and override the request values before you use it to update the `$customer`. Consider adding [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation); then you can use the `$request->validated()` function instead of the `$request->all()` function to prevent `mass assignment vulnerability`.